# Emacs auto-display of things at point in a right window

Tags: emacs

I'd like to implement a function it shows relevant code paragraph in its right window when Emacs cursor is prompting on a certain word.

Let's assume that I have my own log format and I have corresponding database which I can find where a log message came from then I have the pointer on a certain log message. If so, then I like to let Emacs open the corresponding source file in a right side window of that log buffer.
Now I can query and get the location of source file thru my own db and emacs. But I still don't know how to control the right window.

If I opened a right window once, then Emacs would open an another one again, I don't want to let it do but want to let it use the previous, existing window.
How could I implement this? Please advise me, or share an example you might have.

Thanks.

Comment: org-mode has something similar in the agenda view, you can follow using follow-mode, and as you move the pointer through the agenda item, the pointer in the parallel window skips to the relevant task.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the examples below using the custom function `my-display-buffer`, keep in mind that BUFFER can be obtained by means other than `find-file-noselect`; e.g., `current-buffer` if so desired.  In terms of finding your location in the other window, you may find it helpful to `select-window` or `with-selected-window` or `set-window-point`, etc.  If the window is selected with the target buffer visible in said window, then simple things like `goto-char` will suffice to go visually to a particular location.  The example `my-display-buffer` function has a doc-string which describes generally what it was designed to do; i.e., "There are three possibilities ...".

**Display buffer to the left**:

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'left))
```

**Display buffer to the right:**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'right))
```

**Display buffer above:**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'above))
```

**Display buffer below:**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'below))
```

```lisp
(defun my-display-buffer (buffer-or-name alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
"BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
There are three possibilities:
-  (1) If a window on the frame already displays the target buffer,
then just reuse the same window.
-  (2) If there is already a window in the specified direction in relation
to the selected window, then display the target buffer in said window.
-  (3) If there is no window in the specified direction, then create one
in that direction and display the target buffer in said window."
  (let* ((buffer
           (if (bufferp buffer-or-name)
             buffer-or-name
             (get-buffer buffer-or-name)))
         (window
           (cond
             ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
             ((window-in-direction direction))
             (t
               (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
    (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    window))
```